# Can't get Stardog to run on Mac OS X

Tags: java, stardog

I just download Stardog and I'm trying to run it on my machine (Mac OS X 10.14.2).

I use `ZSH` shell and I have added the following two lines in my `.zshrc` file:

```
export STARDOG_HOME="/Applications/stardog-6.1.0"
export PATH="$PATH:$STARDOG_HOME/bin"
```

Following is my entire `$PATH` variable:

```
➜  echo $PATH
/Users/my_user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/stardog-6.1.0/bin
```

Following is my java version:

```
➜  java --version
openjdk 11.0.1 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
```

I copied the license in `/Applications/stardog-6.1.0` and then I try to run 
`stardog-admin server start` but that's the output:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2 (file:/Applications/stardog-6.1.0/client/api/guice-4.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
WARN  2019-01-25 13:50:03,228 [main] com.complexible.common.memory.PlatformDependent:<init>(144): sun.misc.VM is not available
There was an error initializing Stardog; one or more dependencies could not be satisfied. Please verify your classpath is correct.
The initialization errors were:
 *  Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        com.complexible.stardog.StardogKernel.<init>()
        com.complexible.stardog.StardogKernel
    Caused by:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.complexible.memory.memoryblock.MemoryBlockPool.allocateAll(MemoryBlockPool.java:181)
    at com.complexible.memory.memoryblock.MemoryBlockPool.<init>(MemoryBlockPool.java:50)
    at com.complexible.memory.memoryblock.MemoryContext.createMemoryBlockPool(MemoryContext.java:180)
    at com.complexible.memory.memoryblock.MemoryContext.<init>(MemoryContext.java:65)
    at com.complexible.stardog.StardogKernel.initMemoryContext(StardogKernel.java:703)
    at com.complexible.stardog.StardogKernel.<init>(StardogKernel.java:491)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at com.complexible.stardog.Stardog.initKernel(Stardog.java:213)
    at com.complexible.stardog.Stardog.<init>(Stardog.java:206)
    at com.complexible.stardog.Stardog.<init>(Stardog.java:60)
    at com.complexible.stardog.Stardog$StardogBuilder.create(Stardog.java:597)
    at com.complexible.stardog.cli.impl.ServerStart.call(ServerStart.java:165)
    at com.complexible.stardog.cli.impl.ServerStart.call(ServerStart.java:41)
    at com.complexible.stardog.cli.CLIBase.execute(CLIBase.java:55)
    at com.complexible.stardog.cli.admin.CLI.main(CLI.java:187)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils.isJavaVersionAtLeast(SystemUtils.java:1642)
    at com.complexible.memory.util.MMBits.<clinit>(MMBits.java:37)
    ... 32 more
Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at com.complexible.stardog.StardogKernel.<init>(StardogKernel.java:277)
  at com.complexible.stardog.StardogKernel.class(StardogKernel.java:277)
  while locating com.complexible.stardog.StardogKernel
  while locating com.complexible.stardog.Kernel
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like Stardog is not compatible with JDK 11. Try installing JDK 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.stardog.com/docs/) for Stardog (Stardog 6.1.0 (16 Jan 2019))  states:

> ### Requirements
>
> It just doesn’t get any easier than this: Stardog runs on Java 8.

---

Install Java 8.

I expect that in the fullness of time, the vendors of Stardog will release a version that works on Java 11, but I couldn't see any announcements on their site.  (There is a Stardog 7.0.0 Beta ... but the release notes don't mention Java 11.)

---

Update: Stardog 9.0 has updated to Java 11; see the [release notes](https://docs.stardog.com/release-notes/stardog-platform#900-release-2023-04-05).  The [system requirements](https://docs.stardog.com/install-stardog/system-requirements) page currently says that only Java 11 is supported.

The take away is ... check the Stardog documentation for the version *that you are trying to use*.